# Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead

Tags: json, swift

I can not pars data from fixtures array, every time I get a mistake

error in console log:

> downloaded
>   Error info: typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [LiveZscores.EventsFull.(CodingKeys in _B768B663C3B4834FEE8438F5C59CA80A).fixtures, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), LiveZscores.EventsData.(CodingKeys in _B768B663C3B4834FEE8438F5C59CA80A).result], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

My code:

ViewController.swift

```
final let url = URL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    downloadJson()

}

func downloadJson() {
    guard let downloadURL = url else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print ("something")
            return
        }
        print ("downloaded")
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let events = try decoder.decode(EventsFull.self, from: data)
            print (events.fixtures)

        }catch {
            print("Error info: \(error)")
        }


    }.resume()

}
```

Events.swift

```
class EventsFull: Codable {
    let fixtures: [EventsData]

    init(fixtures: [EventsData]) {
        self.fixtures = fixtures
    }
}

class EventsData: Codable {

    let date: String
    let status: String
    let matchday: Int
    let homeTeamName: String
    let awayTeamName: String
    let result: String
    let odds: Double

    init(date: String, status: String, matchday: Int, homeTeamName: String, awayTeamName: String, result: String, odds: Double) {

        self.date = date
        self.status = status
        self.matchday = matchday
        self.homeTeamName = homeTeamName
        self.awayTeamName = awayTeamName
        self.result = result
        self.odds = odds
    }

}
```

Comment: From your JSON (got from the link): `"result": {"goalsHomeTeam": null,"goalsAwayTeam": null}`. That's a Dictionary, but you wrote `let result: String`. `result` should be a Dictionary, not a String, that's why you get an error.

Comment: Also, note that there is this possibility: `"result": {"goalsHomeTeam": 2,"goalsAwayTeam": 2,"halfTime":{"goalsHomeTeam": 1,"goalsAwayTeam": 0}`. So I'd suggest to review your `result` and maybe create a new class from it (or if you are just interested in the final score, just read the 2 values, not the `halfTime` one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please learn to read error messages, especially `Codable` messages are very easy to read.

This is the message a bit more structured

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, 
         Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [LiveZscores.EventsFull.(CodingKeys in _B768B663C3B4834FEE8438F5C59CA80A).fixtures, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), 
                                                  LiveZscores.EventsData.(CodingKeys in _B768B663C3B4834FEE8438F5C59CA80A).result], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

`Swift.String` is the expected type in the struct / class

The most significant `codingPath` information is

```
codingPath: [LiveZscores.EventsFull.fixtures, 
             LiveZscores.EventsData.result], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

The error occurred in the key `result` in the struct `EventsData` which is in the struct `EventsFull` for key `fixtures` and the message tells you clearly what's wrong

Take a look at the JSON: The value for key `result` is a dictionary which can be represented by another struct.

---

Normally you don't need a class inherited from `NSObject` to decode JSON, a struct is sufficient and you don't need an initializer, the `Codable` protocol provides the initializer.

All keys which can be `null` must be declared as optional, both keys in `Result` and the key `odds` in `EventsData` can be `null`.

```
struct EventsFull: Decodable {
    let fixtures: [EventsData]
}

struct EventsData: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let status: String
    let matchday: Int
    let homeTeamName: String
    let awayTeamName: String
    let result: Result
    let odds: Double?
}

struct Result : Decodable {
    let goalsHomeTeam : Int?
    let goalsAwayTeam : Int?
}
```